# mysql client binary size zero

Tags: mysql, debian, undelete

I was using the openpanel-mod-mysql module when I kept getting weird error messages.

Then I set out to execute the commands manually and got no response from mysql.

I mean, when I typed in `mysql`, nothing would happen. So, I got a listing of `/usr/bin` and then saw that the size of the mysql binary was now zero. Is there anyway that I could get my hands on another copy of mysql-5.1.63 for debian binary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you somehow managed to modify your MySQL client binaries, just reinstall them with your package management. For Debian Lenny/Squeeze that would be

```
# aptitude reinstall mysql-client-5.1
```

Comment: I actually could not do this, since I had tons of irremovable stuff dependent on mysql-client. What I ended up doing was I snatched the binary from another VPS I owned and made that executable on my own machine, and now it's back to normal.

Comment: The accept and +1 is for even reading through the stupid question and as a thank you for attempting to help a stupid sysadmin who forgot to take backups ;-)